# Using ensurepip to install pip

Tags: python

I am trying to ensure that a library is installed in a blender instance.

I found out about ensurepip and am attempting to use it to install pip.  Then I can install the external library.

However `ensurepip.bootstrap()` gives me the following error:

```
ensurepip.bootstrap()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.74\python\lib\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 116, in bootstrap
_run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.74\python\lib\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 40, in _run_pip
import pip
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqn93iwq6\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqn93iwq6\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\log.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqn93iwq6\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\backwardcompat\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'distutils'
```

Comment: Blender doesn't come with a full standard Python library. You'll have to equip it with distutils first.

Comment: And the simplest way to install pip after you've installed distutils is via the interpeter: `python -m ensurepip`